# Consolidate single-file modules into single module?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

Using TypeScript 2.0.10, I want to consolidate my "model" modules which are in separate files into a single definition.

```
/lib/models
        |-- model-a.ts
        |-- model-b.ts
        |-- model-c.ts
        |-- models.ts
```

I have to import this using relative paths, e.g.: `import {ModelA} from "../../lib/models/model-a`

I want to import like this instead: `import {ModelA} from "models";

I have conglomerated all models into `models.ts`:

**/lib/models/models.ts**

```
declare module models {
    export { ModelA } from "./model-a";
    export { ModelB } from "./model-b";
    export { ModelC } from "./model-c";
}
```

I'm using SystemJS so I am able to do this:

```
paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "models": "dist/models/models",
    "services": "dist/services/*",
    // ...
}
```

Currently, compilation will fail because TypeScript doesn't know how to find `models/*`, but this works fine in the browser sinve I have SystemJS paths configured. Is there a way to setup this same sort of mapping in `tsconfig`?

**Edit** Reworded this a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaumer: This doesn't use modules!** (But I think you still achieve the same effect).

I haven't tried this with system JS, but this should make typescript happy.

**models/index.ts**

```
import { ModelA } from './model-a';
import { ModelB } from './model-c';

export {
    ModelA,
    ModelB
};
```

**somewhere-else.ts**

```
import { ModelA, ModelB } from './models';
```

Comment: Thanks. I would still have to use relative paths (e.g. `../../lib/models`). I'm really looking to simplify this as I don't want to have to "calculate" the relative path every time I need to import a model or service (literally every page/class/etc. in my project.

Comment: @JoshM. oh snap! I don't think I realized this is what modules did. If you figure this out, please update this question with your solution. I'm extremely interested now!